# Border Image is not recognizing section content

Tags: html, css

This is in reference from my previous question:
[How to call a script inside a script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52197423/how-to-call-a-script-inside-a-script/52197621?noredirect=1#comment91348455_52197621)

**PROBLEM** The border image is not covering the whole content:
[image: sample content]

This is currently the code I am working on. [CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/UmaruHime/pen/ZMJZwP) . **NOTE:** I combined 2 css file in code pen since i needed both. I needed the border to cover the section area. And it must adjust automatically depending on the content length. Supposedly, similar to [this](https://codepen.io/UmaruHime/pen/BORbqR).

here is the summarized code:

```css
.content2 {
  margin: auto 0;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  padding: 15px;
  -webkit-border-image: url('https://image.ibb.co/f7kxxz/border.png') 30 stretch;
  /* Safari 3.1-5 */
  -o-border-image: url('https://image.ibb.co/f7kxxz/border.png') 30 stretch;
  /* Opera 11-12.1 */
  border-image: url('https://image.ibb.co/f7kxxz/border.png') 30 stretch;
}
```

```html
<div id='pages'>
  <div class='mydivshow div1' style='display: block;'>
    <section class='content2'>
      <h1> A </h1>
      <p> A is for Atkinson, first name James, an enterprising gentleman from the wildest reaches of northern England, who, on a fine morning in the early spring of 1799, set forth, with a large brown bear.</p>
    </section>
  </div>
```

Can anyone help me figure out as to why the section .content is not covering the h1 and p?

Comment: the code you posted doesn't reproduce the issue, check I have made it a snippet ... and there is nothing in your codepen too ... try to put all the needed code in the question, not only a portion of it

Comment: For me it works just fine, Chrome. Did you clear your cache?

Comment: Seems like your content is `display: float` or `position: absolute`. But it's not from your provided code

Comment: @Justinas You are absolutely right. `.selectedArea .copyArea.fadeIn p { float: left; }` causes the border to jump up. Without this rule, the border works fine.

Comment: @D.Schaller I tried to clear the cache file but somehow, it still produces the same result. All the codes are written on the CODEPEN link I added above.

Comment: @TemaniAfif, if I try to put in all the code, stackoverflow will not allow me "Body is limited to 30000 characters; you entered 51998." That is why I linked it to a codepen instead. My codepen also shows a wrong output similar to my localhost

Comment: also, the .selectedArea is being used in the main code (the whole page itself, that is why I cannot make any changes to it else, it will affect the the output of the stylish menu

Comment: @UmaruHime You don't necessarily need to change something on `.selectedArea`. You could just give the paragraph a class and override the float for them there, without touching the existing rule.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix my own problem. And here is what I did:

I was able to locate which area i the code is affecting the logo and social. When I tried to put !important as per advise, nothing changed. So I did an internal style instead and added it on the header tag

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Sabreen's Seafood Market &amp; Restaurant</title>
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >

    <link href="css/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/nav.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="images/seafood-favicon.png"/>

  <style type="text/css">
    .fa {
      width: 30px !important;
      height: 30px !important;
    }
    .logo img {
    max-height: 200px !important;
  }
  </style>
</head>
```